# can't get Stockfish in Python to work, throws FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, spyder

I want to write a chess related program, where I need to evaluate moves. For this purpose, I have installed the python stockfish package from https://github.com/zhelyabuzhsky/stockfish.

But when I test even one line, with

```
from stockfish import Stockfish

stockfish = Stockfish()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-fef147213e5f>", line 1, in <module>
    stockfish = Stockfish()

  File "C:\Users\ajdin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stockfish.py", line 27, in __init__
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE

  File "C:\Users\ajdin\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\ajdin\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've also tried the same thing with a similar package from https://github.com/iamjarret/pystockfish with the pystockfish package, but the same error arose. (only now the main code was `deep = Engine(depth=20)` ).

I've searched online for this error, but couldn't really find a solution. Does anyone know what is wrong, am I missing any files here?
Any more required info, I am happy to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases my pathfile "stockfish" was incorrect. It needed the full pathname as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
from stockfish.models import Stockfish
```

the notation given in the docs is not working for me too. But while looking into the module file, i came to know the right path for Stockfish.

yet the stockfish application is not correctly decoded while providing the path.
anyone could help with that.